# Material UI table : Old data gets appended to new data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I have created a material ui table. I have an input field , user types in and clicks submit button to load data. Every time the button is clicked ; data is loaded in the table.
However, it is not clearing old data. Old data is still there and new data is getting appended to it. I want just the new data to be there in table clearing the old data. I know that I am not setting data properly. I need help in this.

Parent Component :

```
const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState([]);
  const [tableSearch, setTableSearch] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
    setTableSearch(tableSearch);
  }, [tableSearch]); // 
const handleSearch = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    

    var config = {
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:3000/api/",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      data: form,
    };

    axios(config)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log("Data:", res);
        if (res && res.status) {
          if (res.status === 201) {
            console.log("Data is: inside", form.keyword);

            setSearchQuery([]);
            setTableSearch([]);
            forceUpdate((n) => !n);

            const ItemSearched = res.data.success.filter((obj) => {
              if (obj.location_Mnemonic_Code.includes(form.keyword)) {
                return true;
              } else {
                return false;
              }
            });

            
            console.log("ItemSearched:", ItemSearched, form.keyword);
            ItemSearched.sort((a, b) => parseFloat(b.weightage) - parseFloat(a.weightage));
            
            setSearchQuery(ItemSearched);
            setTableSearch(ItemSearched);
            forceUpdate((n) => !n);

            if (ItemSearched.length === 0) {
              setToastMessage(`Sorry! Couldn't find data for ${form.keyword}`);
            } else {
              setToastMessage("");
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Data is:", res);
            setToastMessage(res.response.message);
          }
        } else {
          setToastMessage(`Sorry! Couldn't find data for ${form.keyword}`);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        if (error && error.response) {
          if (error.response.status === 400) {
            setToastMessage(error.response.data.message[0]);
          }
        }
      });
  };
<input className="input-field" type="text" placeholder="Keyword" name="keyword" value={form.keyword} onChange={handleChange} />
<button type="button" onClick={handleSearch} className="button">
                Search
</button>  
<div className="col-12">
          <TableView dataSource={tableSearch}/>
 </div>
```

Comment: You need to reset data in table or input?

Comment: Hi . I need to reset it in the table.

Comment: modify the `tableSearch` data

Comment: yes , I am modifying using setTableSearch. once I set using setTableSearch, the array is setting . but the table contents still shows the old data; new data is appended. I want just the new data to be in in the table

Comment: your code looks fine, might be some small mistakes. Check on networks, if you getting new response or still old one.

Comment: response is fine.